# Xamarin forms - Cannot get object from REST API to xaml page

Tags: rest, xamarin.forms

I am developing an Xamarin.Forms app in VS 2019. My REST API is hosted on GoDaddy.
When I call the api I get back my json converted object fine in my viewmodel. But the object is null
from my xaml page. See this code:

```
public class NewOrderViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

    public NewOrderDetails NewOrderDetails { get; set; }
    public ICommand OkCommand { get; private set;}
    public ICommand CancelCommand { get; private set; }
    readonly IPageService _pageService;

    public NewOrderViewModel(IPageService pageService, int custId)
    {
        _pageService = pageService;
        OkCommand = new Command(NewOrder);
        CancelCommand = new Command(CancelOrder);
        NewOrderDetails = new NewOrderDetails();

        LoadNewOrderDetails(custId);
     }
    private async void LoadNewOrderDetails(int custId)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient(new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler()))
        {

            var response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://api.lates.com.au/api/Customers/" + custId.ToString());
            var customer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(response);

            await _pageService.DisplayAlert("Value", customer.CustomerName, "OK"); //This confirms the correct customer is returned.
             NewOrderDetails.CustomerName = customer.CustomerName;
            foreach (var cd in customer.CustomerDepartments)
            {
                NewOrderDetails.CustomerDepartments.Add(cd);
            }
            NewOrderDetails.OrderDate = DateTime.Today;
            NewOrderDetails.DeliveryDate = DateTime.Today;
            NewOrderDetails.CustomerId = custId;
         }
    }

    private void NewOrder()
    {
        _pageService.PopAsync();
        _pageService.PushModalAsync(new CustomerOrder());
    }

    private void CancelOrder()
    {
        _pageService.PopAsync();
    }
}


public partial class NewOrder : ContentPage
{
    public NewOrder()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        imgAddIcon.Source = FileImageSource.FromFile("AddDocument64By64.png");

    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        BindingContext = new NewOrderViewModel(new PageService(), 1);
//If i put a break point here the NewOrderDetails property of NewOrderViewModel is null - WHY???
    }
}
```

It seems to be something to do with asynchronous timing. Let me know if you need more info.

Malcolm

Comment: you should read the docs on using async/await

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If i put a break point here the NewOrderDetails property of
>   NewOrderViewModel is null - WHY???

At that time your break point hit, the data in `NewOrderDetails` has not be set because the httpRequest is still requesting and you have to await the request finish to get the data from `Api`.

To solve your problem, you have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in both `NewOrderDetails` and `NewOrderViewModel` to notify the View update value after you get the data from Api. I will give you some code snippets:

In `NewOrderDetails` :

```
public class NewOrderDetails : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public NewOrderDetails()
    {

    }
    public string CustomerName
    {
        set
        {
            if (customerName != value)
            {
                customerName = value;

                OnPropertyChanged("CustomerName");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return customerName;
        }
    }
    string customerName { get; set; }
}
```

In `NewOrderViewModel` :

```
public class NewOrderViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public NewOrderDetails NewOrderDetaila
    {
        set
        {
            if (newOrderDetails != value)
            {
                newOrderDetails = value;

                OnPropertyChanged("NewOrderDetaila");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return newOrderDetails;
        }
    }
    NewOrderDetails newOrderDetails { get; set; }


    public NewOrderViewModel( int custId)
    {

        NewOrderDetaila = new NewOrderDetails();

        LoadNewOrderDetails(custId);
    }
    private async void LoadNewOrderDetails(int custId)
    {
        //...
        NewOrderDetaila.CustomerName = "133"; 
        //...
    }
}
```

And in `Xaml` binding:

```
<Label Text="{Binding NewOrderDetaila.CustomerName}" 
   HorizontalOptions="Center"
   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

Try and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Jack, I have also a collection in the NewOrderDetails class that I add to a Pcker control but it is empty when I bind the page. I have tried this        public virtual IList<CustomerDepartment> CustomerDepartments
        {
            get
            {
                return customerDepartments;
            }
            set
            {
                if (customerDepartments != value)
                {
                    customerDepartments = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

Comment: @user8717499 Try to define the `CustomerDepartments`  as `ObservableCollection` type instead of `IList`.

Answer (score 0):

One problem in your code is here:

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient(new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler()))
    {

        var response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://api.lates.com.au/api/Customers/" + custId.ToString());
        var customer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(response);

        await _pageService.DisplayAlert("Value", customer.CustomerName, "OK"); //This confirms the correct customer is returned.
         NewOrderDetails.CustomerName = customer.CustomerName;
        foreach (var cd in customer.CustomerDepartments)
        {
            NewOrderDetails.CustomerDepartments.Add(cd);
        }
        NewOrderDetails.OrderDate = DateTime.Today;
        NewOrderDetails.DeliveryDate = DateTime.Today;
        NewOrderDetails.CustomerId = custId;
     }
```

HttpClient should be defined as static class, and reused during your application lifetime. Disposing and recreating HttpClient leads to socket errors. Your code is causing multiple requests. I suggest also move this method to Task, that returns the object.

Example method:

```
    internal class SendData
{

    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    internal static async Task<string> MakeServerRequest(string url, string content)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var result = await client.PostAsync(url, request);
            var response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            YOUR ADDITIONAL LOGIC HERE
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This will return JSON string that you can serialize to object, and do whatever your app requires.